# Google adwords app install campaign: UTM parameter tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-ads-api, mixpanel, event-tracking

I am running an Universal app install campaign through google adwords.

In ads setting, I couldn't find a manual URL option as it directly associates your app install campaign to the app listed in google playstore.
I want to track the UTM parameter through URL to track the source campaign for my app installs in a 3rd party software.

I believe GA uses firebase SDK to be included with the app. But we already have the mixpanel sdk integrated in out app to track the camapigns through mixpanel.

Also, If a user uses any other ad campaign (say, custom campaign on face book), the user would be charged for each click (or, impressions) or landing page visit rather than for every app install. Also, facebook dis-approves such ads (custom built, which leads to app install) and asks to use the app install campaign.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @shubhamagwawal did u find anything related to this? I'm facing the same problem.